# How to understand this differential equation notation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation

I have this assignment in my study materials:

$$x' = t x^2 - t$$

With the starting conditions:

- $x(0) = 0$
- $x(1) = -1$
- $x(-1) = 1$

I'm not sure how to understand this notation so that I can solve the equation. Where is $dx$? What I'm used to is something like $\frac{dy}{dx} = something$.

Comment: $x^{'}=\frac{dx}{dt}$.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that you don't know that notation- it's fairly standard. $x'= \frac{dx}{dt}$ so this equation is $\frac{dx}{dt}= tx^2- t= t(x^2- 1)$.  That is "separable".  You can rearrange it as $\frac{dx}{x^2- 1}= t dt$ and integrate both sides.

Comment: @user247327 I just started to learn differential equations. I don't even know how to solve the one above, but first I at least needed to make some sense out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we are in the case that $x$ has only dependence on $t$, $x'$ unambiguously denotes $\frac{dx}{dt}$. So, your problem is :
$$ \frac{dx}{dt}=tx^2-t$$
subject to the conditions $x(0)=0,x(-1)=1, x(1)=-1$.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to correctly enter it into wolfram alpha?

Comment: This string should work: "dx/dt=tx^2-t, x(0)=0, x(-1)=1, x(1)=-1." If you want to know how to solve this, read about separable ODE's.

Comment: As the initial conditions have all the form $x(a)=-a$, WA gives the solution as [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%28t%29%3Dt*%28x%28t%29^2-1%29,+x%28a%29%3D-a).